# Match At least 1 uppercase, 1 special, 4 non-sequential numbers, length is 6 to 14

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to match at least 1 uppercase anywhere, 1 special anywhere, 4 non-sequential numbers anywhere and length is 6 to 14.

I tried the following regex:

> `((?=(.*[^A-Za-z0-9])+)(?=(.*[A-Z])+)(?=(.*\d){4,})(?=.*[a-z])+)(?!=.*([\d])\\1\\1\\1\\1).{6,14}`

But all the following strings are matching:

```
abDc#E0%F9$845, 
abDc#E0%F9$8y6, 
abDc#E0981, 
#ab1DcE09w1234  **(4 sequential numbers)**, 
#ab1111DcE09, 
E$ab1Dc098, 
1$Eab1Dc0989, 
T3$s7p4s$123, 
T1234$stPass    **(4 sequential numbers)**
```

And doesn't match:

```
testpass, 
abDc#E0%F9$8y67 (15 characters), 
t3stpass, 
te$stpass, 
TestPass, 
T3$stpass
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Isn't that what you want? You said 6-14 chars and 15 is not between 6 and 14.

Comment: But some have 4 sequential numbers

Comment: Ah yes. Nothing that says "1 uppercase anywhere, 1 special anywhere, 4 non-sequential numbers anywhere and length 6 to 14" as clear as a line's worth of keyboard mashing with SHIFT pressed. You should consider replacing this mess with proper readable code. Regex is good for a whole lot of tasks, but this is not one of them.

Comment: You mean PHP functions for checking uppercase characters etc? one preg_match_all for each step

Comment: You aren't obliged to put all checks in one huge regexp, are you? You can check it using 4 smaller and less complicated regexps.

Comment: if(preg_match('/.*{6,14}/', $senha, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE)) {
            if(preg_match('/[a-zA-Z]/', $senha, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE)) {
                if(preg_match('/\d/', $senha, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE)) {
                    if(preg_match('/[^a-zA-Z\d]/', $senha, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE)) {
                        /* do something */
                    }
                }
            }
        }

something like this?

Comment: OOps... I can check length with strlen -_-

Comment: "at least 1 uppercase anywhere": use preg_match(). "1 special anywhere": use preg_match(). "4 non-sequential numbers anywhere": use preg_match_all() and extract all numbers into a string or array, and then step through the string or array checking for sequences. "length is 6 to 14": strlen().

Comment: For the sequential numbers, my tests concluded the following regex is working: #(?=.*[0-9]{1}.*[0-9]{1}.*[0-9]{1}.*[0-9]{1})# and I don't need to use arrays (because the quantity is small, of course)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
if (preg_match('/^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=(?:.*\d){4,})(?=.*[!@$%^&*()_+=-]).{6,14}$/', $string)) {
    // remove all non digit
    $tmp = preg_replace('/\D+/', '', $string);
    if (preg_match('/0123|1234|2345|3456|4567|5678|6789|3210|4321|5432|6543|7654|8765|9876|0000|1111|2222|3333|4444|5555|6666|7777|8888|9999/', $string)) {
        echo "Failed\n";
    }
    echo "Pass\n";
} else {
    echo "Failed\n";
}
```

**Where:**

```
(?=.*[A-Z])             : at least one uppercase
(?=(?:.*\d){4,})        : at least 4 digits
(?=.*[!@$%^&*()_+=-])   : at least one special character
.{6,14}                 : from 6 to 14 character long
```

Comment: Perfect! Just add a `)` before `{` in the first line.

Comment: What's the use of the colon in `(?=(?:.*\d){4,})`?

Comment: @RodrigoSiejaBertin: `(?:...)` is a non-capture group, see: http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html

Comment: Hm... So if I don't use the colon, it "stops" when the first digit is found?

Comment: @RodrigoSiejaBertin: The colon comes with `(?`, without it produces an error. `(?:...)` groups data in the same way than `(...)` except that you can't access with the notation `$1`. It's more effecient but if you want to use the data captured you have to use `(...)`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, please test it before using it:

```
function validate_password($password){

 if(empty($password))
  return false;

 if(strlen($password) < 4 || strlen($password) > 14)
  return false;

 $uppercase_test = preg_match('#[A-Z]+#', $password);

 //include special charactors that you want
 $special_test = preg_match('#[!@$%^&*()_+=-]+#', $password);

 $nonsequencial_number_test = !preg_match('#(\d)\\1{4,}#', $password);

 if($uppercase_test && $special_test && $nonsequencial_number_test){
  return true;
 }

 return false;

}
var_dump(validate_password('abDc#E0%F9$8y6'));
```

Comment: Heh. It still doesn't do what the OP was asking though. `(\d)\\1{4,}` will only detect strings like `1111` or `2222`. That is *not* what the OP was asking. He/she wants to detect consecutive (or sequential) numbers, like: `1234`, `5678` etc. That's not something easily possible with regex.

Comment: And inverse sequential numbers like 4321. But $t1111rinG is ok according to !preg_match('#(\d)\\1{4,}#', $password)

Comment: Changed to (0123|1234|2345|3456|4567|5678|6789|3210|4321|5432|6543|7654|8765|9876|0000|1111|2222|3333|4444|5555|6666|7777|8888|9999) but it only checks if there's some sequence like these... I must add regex for "it has 4 numbers"

Comment: Used #(?=.*\d){4,}# to check if it has 4 numbers anywhere, but it doesn't work... matching ok for a$123A
EDIT: changed to #(?=.*\d{4,})# and it's working now... going to answer

Comment: @AmalMurali: this is a sample code that helps OP to justify.

Comment: T1e2$3t4 didn't pass, so the problem is in my 2nd preg_match (see code in my answer). It's searching 4 numbers IN A ROW, not 4 numbers in ANY position

Answer (score 0):

Used the following PHP page to test the regex.


1) strlen checks string length

2) first preg_match checks one or more uppercase letter

3) second preg_match checks at least 4 numbers

4) third preg_match checks 4 sequential numbers (ascending and descending)

5) fourth preg_match checks at least one special character

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['string'])) {
    if ($_GET['string'] != '') {
        $string = $_GET['string'];
    } else {
        echo "Empty string.";
    }
}
?>
<pre>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Regular Expression Tester</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action="" method="get">
      <input type="text" name="string" />
      <input type="submit" value="Send" />
</form>
</pre>
<?php
if (isset($_GET['string'])) {

    if(strlen($string) >= 6 && strlen($string) <= 14) { // length between 6 and 14
        echo "Size between 6 and 14: <b><span style=\"color:green;\">OK</span></b>", "<br>";

        if (preg_match('#[A-Z]+#', $string)) { // one or more uppercase chars
            echo utf8_decode("At least one uppercase: <b><span style=\"color:green;\">OK</span></b>"), "<br>";

            if (preg_match('#(?=.*[0-9]{1}.*[0-9]{1}.*[0-9]{1}.*[0-9]{1})#', $string)) { // it has at least 4 numbers anywhere
                if (!preg_match('#(0123|1234|2345|3456|4567|5678|6789|3210|4321|5432|6543|7654|8765|9876|0000|1111|2222|3333|4444|5555|6666|7777|8888|9999)#', $string)) { // sequential numbers
                    echo utf8_decode("4 non-sequential numbers: <b><span style=\"color:green;\">OK</span></b>"), "<br>";

                    if (preg_match('#[!@$%^&*()_+=-]+#', $string)) { // special chars
                        echo utf8_decode("At least one special character: <b><span style=\"color:green;\">OK</span></b>"), "<br>";
                        echo utf8_decode("<br>$string <b><span style=\"color:green;\">PASSED</span></b>");
                        exit;

                    } else {
                        echo utf8_decode("At least one special character: <b><span style=\"color:red;\">FAILED</span></b>"), "<br>";
                    }

                } else {
                    echo utf8_decode("4 non-sequential numbers: <b><span style=\"color:red;\">FAILED</span></b>"), "<br>";
                }
            } else {
                echo utf8_decode("4 non-sequential numbers: <b><span style=\"color:red;\">FAILED</span></b>"), "<br>";
            }

        } else {
            echo utf8_decode("At least one uppercase: <b><span style=\"color:red;\">FAILED</span></b>"), "<br>";
        }

    } else {
        echo "Size between 6 and 14: <b><span style=\"color:red;\">FAILED</span></b>", "<br>";
    }

    echo utf8_decode("<br>$string <b><span style=\"color:red;\">DIDN'T PASS</span></b>");
}
?>
  <pre>
  </body>
</html>
</pre>
```

Screenshots:

[image: regex tester 1]

[image: regex tester 2]

[image: regex tester 3]

EDIT: But `T1e2$3t4` didn't pass, so the problem is in the 2nd preg_match. It's searching 4 numbers IN A ROW, not 4 numbers in ANY position.

EDIT 2: Changed that regex to `#(?=.*[0-9]{1}.*[0-9]{1}.*[0-9]{1}.*[0-9]{1})#` and it's working completely now.

Thanks, everyone! :-)

Comment: My test page says `1eW23tua4 5` is OK (also `1eW23tua4` only)

Comment: Yes, you're rigth. My bad :-( Gonna delete my comment.